# My avocado tree is not doing well

Tags: trees, indoors, avocado

My avocado tree has been growing for a year just in the last few days the top has started to droop and bend over sideways the rest of the tree looks healthy but my healthy leaves are falling off. I thought I was over watering it so I cut back but it hasn't helped now the leaves are curling under and turning brown. Please help me
I'm using miracle grow potting soil and it gets plenty of sunshine

Comment: Please add some photos. Also, where are you located? Too harsh of sun or wind could cause that.